# Como simular [mouseup()] elemento por elemento usando get()

Tags: jquery, eventos-do-mouse

Tenho uma aplicação web a qual possuo elementos do tipo *input*.

```
<input class="switch-input" name="0" type="checkbox" />
<input class="switch-input" name="1" type="checkbox" />
<input class="switch-input" name="2" type="checkbox" />
<input class="switch-input" name="3" type="checkbox" />
```

E tenho um código JavaScript o qual preciso setar estes *inputs* para `FALSE` e simular um `MOUSEUP` para que a minha aplicação execute uma ação baseada nisso. Basicamente utilizava:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked", false);
$("input").mouseup();
```

O que funcionou muito bem inicialmente, porém neste caso executa tudo junto e agora preciso de um pequeno delay. Tentei fazer:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked", false);
for(i=0;i < $("input").length; i++)
{
    setTimeout($("input")[i].mouseup(), 100);
}
```

Mas isso me retorna este erro no *console*:

> off-proc-rec.js:29 Uncaught TypeError: $(...)[i].mouseup is not a function

Tentei também utilizando:

```
 setTimeout($("input").eq(i).mouseup(), 100);
```

E obtive este erro:

> VM811:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Alguém tem alguma ideia de maneira para fazer isso?

Comment: Testa assim: https://jsfiddle.net/LkL4ne6a/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma opção é obter as referências dos `inputs` por javascript e, dentro do laço, chamar uma função para desmarcar incrementando o tempo entre as execuções. Algo como:

```js
function go() {
  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");
  var tempo = 100;
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    var name = inputs[i].name;
    tempo = tempo + 500;
    desmarcar(name, tempo);
  }
}

function desmarcar(name, tempo){
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("input[name='"+name+"']").prop("checked", false);
      $("input[name='"+name+"']").mouseup();
    }, tempo);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="switch-input" name="0" type="checkbox" />
<input class="switch-input" name="1" type="checkbox" />
<input class="switch-input" name="2" type="checkbox" />
<input class="switch-input" name="3" type="checkbox" />

<button onclick="go()">Testar</button>
```